# Read multiple csv files into separate dataframes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I like to read two csv files from a particular folder into two separate dataframes.

The two file names are: 23314621_MACI_NAV.CSV and 23314623_MACI_Holding.CSV

The file second part of the file names are fixed MACI_NAV.CSV and MACI_Holding.CSV, however the first part of the file name which are numbers change everyday.

I like to read them into two different dataframe by trying this:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

msci_folder = 'N:/Operation/Daily CDS E_Report/CDS/MACI/'
mscifile = glob.glob(msci_folder + "\*.csv")

for file in mscifile:
    df_nav=pd.read_csv(file)
    df_holding=pd.read_csv(file)
```

It seems like both lines are reading the same file, how do I make them read different files (second file)?

Answer (score 8):

If want create list of DataFrames:

```
dfs = []
for file in mscifile:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dfs.append(df)
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in mscifile]

print (dfs[0])
print (dfs[1])
```

Another solution is create `dictionary of DataFrames` with keys by last substring after `_` in filename:

```
from os.path import splitext, basename

dfs = {splitext(basename(fp))[0].split('_')[-1] : pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in mscifile}
print (dfs)

print (dfs['NAV'])
print (dfs['Holding'])
```